# How do I align my search-input and submit-button to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I know this is super basic but I've been through my coding reference books all day and I think my mind's a little buggered. I need to get BOTH the input field AND the "submit" button in one line, in the center of the page, similar to Google.

```css
.logo {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.input-fields {
  padding: 3%;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.submit {
  padding: 3%;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="OnSaleTodayMobile.png" alt="OnSaleToday.co.za">
</header>
<div class="form-wrapper">    
  <form class="center">
    <input class="input-fields" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for anything...">
    <input class="input-fields submit" name="find" type="submit" value="Find">
  </form>
</div>
```

The problem I'm getting is that the button is stacking underneath the text-field. What am I missing out?

Comment: You're using `display:block` which defaults to this behaviour. Try `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Google has it vertically and horizontally aligned so you should try something like this (simplified version):

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
html, body {width: 100vw; height: 100vh}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-me {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-me > .form-wrapper > .center {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="align-me">
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="OnSaleTodayMobile.png" alt="OnSaleToday.co.za">
  </header>
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form class="center">
      <input class="input-fields" name="search" type="text" placeholder="...">
      <input class="input-fields submit" name="find" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But their design is not responsive and this is.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this example and it works perfectly. I'm only not familiar at all with the flex styling, my CSS reference books recommend them for modern browsing and not for older versions of browsers. I haven't yet come across the "100vw/vh" but they work well on all screen sizes - which is ideal. I intend to eventually use my design on an eCommerce website where there'll be lots of traffic, is this a recommended styling method after all, knowing that there would be plenty of older users?

Comment: Flexbox is easy to learn & master and nowadays plays an important role in responsive web design/development so you should be using it. 100vw & 100vh mean: the 100% of the viewport width & 100% of the viewport height, this is a specific measure of the width and height of the available screen. Of course you should be using Flexbox, the problem is not with older users but in browser versions which should optimally be "up to date". At this url: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox you can take a look at which browser versions fully support Flexbox and as you will see there are many so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the default behaviour of `display:block`.

Using `display:inline-block` will make them *block* elements so you can add padding, etc, but make them *inline* so they will appear beside each other (assuming they fit, and other styles don't change the default behaviour).

Just change the display from `block` to `inline-block` in your CSS here:

```
.input-fields {
    [...]
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Working snippet:**

```css
.logo {width: 50%; display:block; margin:auto;}

.input-fields {
    padding:3%;
    width:40%;
    display:inline-block; /* change this from block to inline-block */
    vertical-align: middle; /* this will help with any vertical alignment issues */
    margin:auto;
    font-size:90%;


    }

.submit {
    padding:3%;
    width:15%;
    } 
   
 /* Add this this to center your inputs - 
    you included the "center" class in your HTML but not it in your CSS */
.center { text-align:center}
```

```html
<header><img class="logo" src="OnSaleTodayMobile.png" alt="OnSaleToday.co.za"/></header>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form class="center">
    <input class="input-fields" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for anything..."/>
    <input class="input-fields submit" name="find" type="submit" value="Find"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: However, the block is used in with "margin:auto" to make the div centralized... If I display it as "inline-block", the searchbox goes back to the left of the page and does not center at all. This is why I can't figure out how to place both the input field And the button on one line, in the center of the page...

Comment: @ArabianMaiden I don't understand the issue? If you run the snippet, it works as expected based on your question. What exactly do you you need it to do differently?

Comment: Hmm..You're right. Though my browser (using Chrome) stacks it up. I've just tried it in IE and Opera as well, it does not centralize the inputs...

Comment: @ArabianMaiden It works fine for me in Chrome, IE11, Edge and FF. Can you show a screengrab of the issue and the exact details of the OS & browser the issue is in? Its difficult to fix a problem we can't recreate :)

Comment: @ArabianMaiden "*the block is used in with "margin:auto" to make the div centralized... If I display it as "inline-block"*"... are you changing the ***div*** to inline-block? That's not correct - You only change the inputs, as per the examples my answer. Or if you have additional styles in your real code that is affecting the behaviour, you need to include those in your question so we can make it work in *that* situation.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I didn't get a chance at my desktop, I'm eager to get down to solving the issue. I will let you guys know as soon as I've tried/played with the answers you gave. Thank you for assisting :)

Comment: I've figured that your examples do work - as you mentioned, if I don't copy the full code you can't figure where the problem lies. My issue starts when I begin to style the inputs. When I add a padding to the input fields, they start to stack up. It's the same whether I use one of your examples, or the answer below with the 'flex' styling method. How does a padding to the inputs change the entire center-styling?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the elements you want to display in line. You currently have 'display: block;' This will push elements on to there own line.

You may also want:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

To make them vertically aligned relative to each other.

To make sure they both stay dead center in the page put them all in a container (or just use your existing form container) and style it like:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
```

This will ensure no matter what the screen size is the container is in the middle both vertically and horizontally.